# How to link address entity to new custom entity in MSCRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Tech Friends,

How to link address entity to new custom entity in MSCRM 2011? I want to do something similar to contact entity which has linked address entity having multiple fields.

The same I want to do for custom entity. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `CustomerAddress` entity is, frustratingly, locked to further relationships. You will need to create another custom entity to use as Address and link that back to `Contact` and `Account` (and hide the built in entity).